# Intermediate Value Theorem proof Question

Tags: real-analysis

There is a certain implication  **$\overset{(*)}{\Longrightarrow}$**  of the proof that I do not understand.

> Intermediatevaluetheorem
>   :$[a,b]\subseteq\mathbb{R},f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}
>  \text{ continuous, }f(a)\leq y_0\leq f(b) \Longrightarrow
>  \exists_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)=y_0$

Proof:

$$\text{Let }M:=\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)\geq y_0\}$$

$$b\in M\Longrightarrow M\neq\emptyset\text{ and }a\leq x,\forall _{x\in M}\Longrightarrow \exists\inf M=:x_0$$

$$\Longrightarrow\exists_{(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}x_n\rightarrow x_0,x_n\in M,\forall_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$$

$$\overset{f\text{ is continuous}}\Longrightarrow f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x_0)\overset{x_n\geq y_0,\forall_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}{\Longrightarrow}f(x_0)\geq y_0\Longrightarrow x_0=\max M$$

$$\text{Suppose }f(x_0)>y_0\Longrightarrow \exists_{\epsilon_0>0}\epsilon_0=f(x_0)-y_0$$

$$\overset{f\text{ is continuous}}{\Longrightarrow}\exists_{\delta_0>0}\forall_{x\in[a,b]}|x-x_0|<\delta_0\Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon_0$$

$$\overset{(*)}{\Longrightarrow}f(x)>f(x_0)-\epsilon_0=y_0\text{ contradicition to }x_0=\inf M$$

$(*)$ Is only true if the $x$ I am looking for is smaller than $x_0$ How do I know that such a $x$ exists.

I.e How can I make sure that $\{(x_0-\delta_0,x_0)\cap[a,b]\}=:S\subset M$ is not empty?

Comment: You can take $\delta$ small enough so that $(x -\delta, x+ \delta) \subset [a,b]$. You can always take smaller $\delta$ in general, as if $\delta_1 < \delta_2$, we have that $|x - a| < \delta_1 \implies |x- a| < \delta_2$

Comment: I do not know how exact your copy of the proof is, but as the version that you have presented here is written very poorly.

Comment: The original proof was in German and there was more text involved...

Answer (score 2):

Take $x=x_0-\delta /2$ in the argument. Note that $|x-x_0|=\delta /2 <\delta$ so we get $|f(x)-f(x_0)| <\epsilon_0$ and hence $f(x) >f(x_0)-\epsilon_0 >y_0$. This is a contradiction since $x <x_0$.